# How to create a radial Rainbow colored clone using Inkscape or Affinity?

Tags: inkscape, affinity

Say I'm using a single colored square - Red.  I want to create a circular (clock style) clone of the square.  Each clone being a different shade (from red to yellow and back to red, for example.

Say, 24 clones, 15 degree shift, 360 degrees total.

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Maybe a Path Effect might also work in Inkscape. Maybe Rotate Copies or Interpolate?

Used Tiled Clones in Inkscape - didn't work.  Tried Using Ctrl-J (Duplicate in Affinity) didn't work.  Using most recent versions of Inkscape / Affinity.

Comment: I think you will get an answer if you ask your question on GDSE: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Would've asked it there, couldn't find it.  Thanks